# SQL IS percentage

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a SQL file with a query like the below, which finds all customers that have an outstanding order value greater than or equal to their credit limit.

```
AND kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen >= kred_lim.kred_limit;
```

How can I find the above, but also customers where for example their outstanding order value is say 90% of their credit limit? Is it possible to use such percentages in a WHERE?

Comment: Isn't this grade school arithmetic?

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
AND kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen = (kred_lim.kred_limit / 100) * 90;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with Darren's answer *except* for the exactness.  Let me assume that by 90%, you really mean between 89.5% and 90.5%.  In that case, you would use a comparison like:

```
AND (kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen/kred_lim.kred_limit)*100 between 89.5 and 90.5;
```